# How to parse GET prarameters in a Python CGI script?

Tags: python

I am trying to parse GET-Parameters from the URL during a CGI execution in Python 3 and Ubuntu. The CGI Funtionality works, but I can not figure out how to retrieve the URL.

If the URL string is provided via variable setting then it works. Using os.environ provides only the query string which is not a valid URL and therefore causes the parse_qs method to fail:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

# test string
url = 'https://www.example.io/cgi-bin/redir.py?rurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.de%2Fde&utm_content=test&utm_campaign=alert&utm_source=mail&utm_medium&monitoring&utm_term=bla&UID=7'

# url = os.environ['QUERY_STRING']
# query_components = dict(qc.split("=") for qc in query.split("&"))

""" Parse GET parameters from URL
    Mandatory parameters:
        - rurl
"""
try:
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    redirect_url = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)['rurl'][0]
    # print(redirect_url)
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Desired result is to retrieve the GET parameter "rurl" from the URL instead from the test variable.

Comment: `parse_qs` isn't defined in yuor code. Please post he actual code you are using?

Comment: I added the libraries, this is a minimal example trying to pin it to the problem.